# display child pages of multiple parents, whilst removing the parent

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

Structure:

- Home

  - Projects

    - Project Pages 1

      - Project 1
    - Project Pages 2

      - Project 2
    - Project Pages 3

      - Project 3

I would like to loop through the Project Categories in order to display the pages in desc order.

I have so far:

```
<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=2&post_type=page&order=DESC&post_parent=61&exclude=168,170,166");


if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

However this is only displaying the project pages, rather than the project itself.  I am not sure if the exclusion is working in the query.

EDIT:

I have found this which returns all child pages using args_merge. I would like to know how I could modify this in order to return only the two most recent posts from all the child pages.

```
<? $args = array( 
             'child_of'    => 61,
             'sort_column' => 'post_date',
             'sort_order'  => 'desc'
        );
$child_pages = get_pages( $args );

$args['child_of'] = 166;
        $second_page_group = get_pages( $args );
        $child_pages = array_merge( $child_pages, $second_page_group );
$args['child_of'] = 168;
        $third_page_group = get_pages( $args );
        $child_pages = array_merge( $child_pages, $third_page_group );
$args['child_of'] = 170;
        $forth_page_group = get_pages( $args );
        $child_pages = array_merge( $child_pages, $forth_page_group );
unset( $second_page_group, $third_page_group, $args );

if( !empty( $child_pages ) )
foreach( $child_pages as $_my_page ) {
    $title   = apply_filters( 'the_title', $_my_page->post_title );
    //$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $_my_page->post_content );
    //$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    $link    = apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $_my_page->ID ) );
                ?>
```

This does seem however slightly excessive. I added the third block and edited slightly form the original post found https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/child-page-from-2-different-parent-pages

Comment: Take a look at wp_list_pages()

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help accomplish it. I have found something else that I am currently testing, will edit if positive.

Comment: just edited the resources I found. Tell me what you think of this @SMacFadyen

Comment: Hmm, it sounds tricky. You want to get your page structure, but limit those pages to only most recent ones?

Comment: yes exactly, however, I want to display only the child pages, in terms of most recent projects not the parent. It kinda has to be in a loop so that I can state that I only want 2 posts/pages displayed. Maybe it may be worth hardcoding the pages in for the moment or using tags, specifying the tags for projects only then displaying 2 posts from there. Hmm dilemma.